# Creating a double link list. Initializing the first 15 nodes

Tags: c++

My insert method should have P as taking in the first value (0) and 15 being the last value of the link list. Though, when I print out my list, I have to go through p->succ instead of p-prev to print out the items, and it prints out 15, 14, 13....; is this right? or am i implementing my functions wrong?

```
 class Node{
      public:
           int value;       
           Node *succ;
           Node *prev;       
                  Node(int val, Node *s=NULL, Node *p=NULL)
                       :value(val),succ(s),prev(p){}

   Node *insert(Node *p,Node *n)
    {
        if(n==NULL)
           return p;
        if(p==NULL)
           return n;
        n->succ=p;
        if(p->prev)
           p->prev->succ=n;
        n->prev=p->prev;
        p->prev=n;           
           return n;
   }

   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Node *p= NULL;

    for(int i = 0; i<=15; i++){

    p = insert(p, new Node(i));
   }

while(p){
    cout<<p->value;
    head=p->succ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding your nodes at the beginning. So obviously the last one added will be the first. If you want the nodes in the order you added, you need to add the nodes at the end.

```
Node *insert(Node *p,Node *n)
{
    Node * ptr;

    if(n==NULL)
       return p;

    if(p==NULL)
       return n;

    ptr = p;

    // Traverse to the end of the list
    while(ptr->succ)
    {
        ptr = ptr->succ;
    }

    ptr->succ = n;
    n->prev = ptr;

    return p;

}
```